# Add line to end of h tag with CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add a line to end of a h tag with CSS like this image:

[image: Adding a line to end of h tag]

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="titleContainer">
<h1 class="titleLeft">how We turn your</h1>
<div class="horizontalLineRight orangeLine" style="width: 213px;"></div>
</div>
```

I set the width of `horizontalLineRight` with jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        $( '.titleContainer' ).each(function() {
            var titleContainerWidth = $(this).width();
            var titleLeftWidth = $(this).find( '.titleLeft' ).outerWidth();
            var titleRightWidth = $(this).find( '.titleRight' ).outerWidth();
            remainingRight = titleContainerWidth - titleLeftWidth - 2;
            remainingLeft = titleContainerWidth - titleRightWidth - 2;
            $(this).find( '.horizontalLineRight' ).css("width", remainingRight);
            $(this).find( '.horizontalLineLeft' ).css("width", remainingLeft);
        });
    });
});
```

It works fine when the h tag doesn't fill 100% width of container.

[image: See this image.]

But when I change the width, the line disappear. I think I have to put `<div class="horizontalLineRight orangeLine">` inside `<div class="titleContainer">` but I don't know how I can calculate remaining width (free space) with jQuery.

Comment: Maybe you can use an empty span (i.e. `<span id='myLine'></span>`) right after the h tag and style it using CSS?

Comment: @AnisR. Thanks for your quick reply. but I tried it with no luck. My problem is the width of this element. How can I set the width for this element?

Comment: @Situdio please show us the markup that you used, not a picture.  Edit your question, click the `<>` button or type Ctrl+M to bring up the on site editor, and make a runnable snippet to show us what you have.

Comment: @Situdio I will put more details in an answer.

Comment: @Taplar the question is now edited with the needed code if you want to cast a reopen vote

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

```css
.titleContainer {
  max-width:400px;
  animation:change 3s linear infinite alternate;
}
.titleLeft {
  background:
     /*the line placed at the bottom of the container*/
     linear-gradient(orange,orange) 0 calc(100% - 0.5em)/100% 2px no-repeat;
  background-color:#000;
}
.titleLeft span {
  /*inherit the background-color and hide the line under the text*/
  background-color:inherit;
  padding:0 5px;
  color:#fff;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {max-width:100px }
}
```

```html
<div class="titleContainer">
<h1 class="titleLeft"><span>how We turn your</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="titleContainer">
<h1 class="titleLeft" style="background-color:red;"><span>how We turn your</span></h1>
</div>
```

In case you want transparency you can try this:

```css
.titleContainer {
  max-width: 400px;
  animation: change 3s linear infinite alternate;
  overflow:hidden; /*you need to hide the extra line width*/
}

.titleLeft span {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
/*the line*/
.titleLeft span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%; /*put at the end of the text*/
  width: 100vw; /*use a big width to be sure to cover the need space*/
  bottom: 0.5em;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {max-width: 100px}
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,red);
}
```

```html
<div class="titleContainer">
  <h1 class="titleLeft"><span>how We turn your</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What a nice trick. It's really instructive. but Is there any way to not set background color for the span? The text has its own background.

Comment: @Situdio you don't need to set background, you simply inherit the one defined in the upper div for the trick to work ... so if the text have its own background simply use it on the upper div

Comment: @Situdio check the update to better understand

Comment: I meant there's a background image behind the text. not a background for text.

Comment: @Situdio share the code where there is a background image and I will adjust my code

Comment: @Situdio I added another way with transparency

Comment: Thank you for your great solution. It works like a charm.

Comment: @Situdio don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know which word (or group of words) you want the line to be next to, you can wrap those words inside a `span` and use `display: flex` + `::after` on the `span` to get the desired effect shown in your first image.

```
<h1>How we turn <span>your</span> business requirements into</h1>
<style>
  h1 span {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  h1 span:after {
    content: "";
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    min-width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
</style>
```

[Here's a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2z9rnl0npj) with a complete example.

If you just want it to take the remaining width of the title space, you shouldn't need to do any jQuery shenanigans with this approach.

Comment: You idea is good but it doesn't work. because the width is not static. It doesn't work properly on mobile devices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Did you look at the codesandbox link? The line in my example takes up all of the remaining space to the right of the text you want to break on.

Answer (score -2):

You could use an empty span with some styling to solve your issue. Try adding `<span id='myLine'></span>` after the h tag, with some CSS styling:

```css
#myLine {
  width: 80%; /*or any percentage that makes it look good for you*/
  /*also set the border bottom to look the way you want, e.g.:*/
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: Please read the updated question.